# Getting AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'rstrip'

Tags: python

I don't understand why I'm getting this message:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rrmenon/Desktop/untitled text 4.py", line 5, in 
    list=fh.rstrip().split()
AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'rstrip'

```
fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)
lst = list()
for line in fh:
    list=fh.rstrip().split()
    if word in lst: continue
    lst.append(word)
lst.sort()
print lst
```

I'm trying to get all words in these strings (four or five sentences), copied in together in one list.  What my Coe currently does (edited based on the suggestions below), is return each sentence as a separate list within a list.  How Do I combine the words in the sentence?

Comment: for **line** in _fh_: list= _fh_.rstrip().split() - you're using **line** variable to store line content and _fh_ variable to store file handle, then you're using rstrip() on file handle. Dude, did you even try to read the message?

Comment: **1** You should open files using a `with` block, but if you don't want to do that you should explicitly `close` the file after you've finished using it.  **2** Your code uses `word` but doesn't define it anywhere. **3** Don't use `list` as a variable name because that masks the built-in `list` type. That will cause weird error messages if you subsequently try to use the `list()` constructor.

Comment: Thanks guys- just learning so appreciate the help. The output I am getting is:  ['But', 'soft', 'what', 'light', 'through', 'yonder', 'window', 'breaks']
['It', 'is', 'the', 'east', 'and', 'Juliet', 'is', 'the', 'sun'].  Each line is broken into its own list...how do I combine the words into one list.  That is why I was trying to do it with the handle before the loop..anyideas?

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty clear: `fh` is a `file` object, which doesn't have a `rstrip` method.

Looks like you want `line.rstrip()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The message is very clear: you're trying to do `fh.rstrip()`, but `rstrip` works on strings, not files; what you probably wanted to do is:

```
list = line.rstrip().split()
```